# Is there any way to change simplex objective function?

Tags: functions, algorithms, simplex

I'm using Simplex Algorithm to solve a material's problem which the objective function should be $x_1 \ln(x_1) + x_2 \ln(x_2) + \dotsb$ to get the best solution.

Is there any way to insert this on the Simplex Algorithm?

Comment: what are the constraints for your optimization problems?

Comment: You want to maximize an entropy ? Is "linear programming" (which encompasses simplex algorithm) is well adapted ? Me to, I ask what are your constraints ? Are they linear ?

Comment: Hi @SiongThyeGoh, what I'm trying to achieve is exactly the maximum entropy. Because sometimes the simplex gives an answer with just one component, and it's not the best solution for my problem (if I achieve 1/n distribution for n components, that would be the best case). As vitreous materials are made by several components (like SiO2, CaO..), I need to mix their properties (like %cov, density..) to achieve new formulations to test in the lab. So, that's why I'm trying to apply this function ln on my problem. Do you have any ideas on how I can use it?

Comment: @JeanMarie, just to notify